# VBA EXCEL: TypeOf doesn't work properly with If

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using typeOf to check if a variable type set as Object is an user-defined type even setting that variable with the right user-defined type typeOf keeps returning false.

How do I fix this issue? Is there another way to do compare a type generic with an especific type of an object?

```
Dim doc As planDOC: Set doc = createObj.doc(config.getDOC, New planDOC, config, rlt)

Public Function doc(str As String, ByVal var As Object, Optional ByVal var2 As Object, Optional ByVal var3 As Object) As Object
    Dim obj As baseDOC: Set obj = New baseDOC
    obj.InitializeProperties var:=str
    If TypeOf var Is planDOC Then
        var.InitializeProperties var:=obj, var1:=var2, var2:=var3
        Set doc = var
        Exit Function
     End If
    If TypeOf var Is formDOC Then
        var.InitializeProperties var:=obj, var2:=var2, var3:=var3
        Set doc = var
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why does the specific type matter? You make exactly the same call for both of the tested types.  I'd suggest making `baseDOC`, `planDOC`, and `formDOC` all implement a common interface (something like `IDoc`) that defines `InitializeProperties`.  Then you can make the `var` parameter strongly typed (`ByVal var As IDoc`) and can skip the type checking completely.

Comment: No-repro. If `baseDOC`, `planDOC` and `formDOC` exist as classes, `TypeOf` works and goes inside the first `If`.

Comment: It should be TypeOf(var)

Comment: @Freeflow `TypeOf` explicitly requires no parentheses in VB6 or VBA. Adding them makes it a compile error. VB.NET compiles, but even there it is redundant.

Comment: Ooops.  Confusing with TypeName